# Can't use css classes from bootstrap using sass

Tags: css, sass

I have a project that I am trying integrate with the twitter bootstrap. I added the bootstrap-responsive.scss and use @import to add it. When I look at the compiled CSS file it shows the entire file but when I go to the HTML and add a class from the bootstrap like .span8 or something the element will not inherit those classes. They do not show when I inspect the element in chrome. Am I doing something wrong here? I figured I had acces to any classes that are in the bootstrap file when I imported it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add bootstrap and bootstrap-responsive. bootstrap-responsive on its own won't work.

Comment: I don't see how that matters because the classes are still in the responsive bootstrap file

Comment: They are only being extended there. bootstrap-responsive is only an extension to the regular bootstrap. It relies on the standard bootstrap file being present.

Comment: I will try your suggestion as soon as I am near my computer again...will let you know if it works